# Declare a CommonJs module as a mixin (JsDoc)

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I have multiple standalone modules who're just mixins used by classes.

Basically, my syntax is exactly this:

```
/** @mixin actions/actions */

var actions = module.exports;

/**
 * Some method
 */
actions.foo = function () {};
```

The file is detected as a mixin, but no method is attached to it inside the API description.

I'm using JsDoc 3.3 and can't find why this isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that work for me. Naming the `@mixin` was the issue as the symbol wasn't recognize on the page. What you need to do is `@alias` it if needed (or keep the variable name).

```
/**
 * @mixin
 * @alias actions/actions
 */
var actions = module.exports;
```